# Setup different environments to build a Yew app for staging, production, development

Tags: rust, yew

I have yew app that should connect to different backend APIs for development, staging and production. How can I set the build process up to build for these different environments?

Answer (score 0):

I should have properly read the docs: https://yew.rs/docs/more/deployment#customizing-behavior-using-environment-variables

In short: use the `std::env!` macro to access env vars during build.